# .net Encrypting Database Tables

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, security, encryption

I am delivering a module for a website that will collect information from a user and make appropriate calculations.  The client wants any data collected from the user to be encrypted.  We are using SQL express 2005 as the database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to avoid your questions being closed, you should phrase them in the form of a question.

Comment: What exactly does the client want? Encrypting the data will make any analysis impossible (i.e. useless feature). Encrypting data on disc is something sql server can do without programming (configuration). Also: UPgrade to a RECENT datadatabase - 2008 R2. 2055 is really old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server already supports [strong encryption](https://web.archive.org/web/20160118171747/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/19/637529.aspx) for columns, why not just use that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Transparent Database Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) because, as the name implies, is transparent for the application and requires absolutely 0 changes. You simply turn on encryption with a one-key-turn: `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ENCRYPTION ON;`. Key management is the simplest possible key management you can get, and the database is protected against accidental loss of media. The encryption carries over to all backups taken, so accidental loss of a backup file will also protect the content.

Answer (score 1):

While encryption in the database is fine (and necessary to protect backups and hard drives from a physical attack or an attack at the OS), since your application has to collect the data and send it to the database, you will need to at least consider several aspects of your application:

Use SSL to protect data from the web browser to your web site (almost certainly necessary)

[Encrypt your connections from the application to the database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx) (may not be necessary if you are running on the same box or if your servers have communication relatively controlled)

Ensure that your application is not vulnerable to exposing data - either through design or implementation defects or injection attacks.

Remember, if your application needs to display data to the client, then the database is going to return that to the app and then the user at some point.  If the app is broken, that data can leak out, regardless of the fact that the data is encrypted in storage and in the channels from browser to app and app to database.

Encrypting data yourself within a database column is almost always pointless since your app will have to decrypt the data before it can be used - the database can do very little with it.  And then your app will need to have some kind of key management.

Answer (score 0):

Heres some [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) goodness.  Mine is in VB but the reference link at the bottom is in C#

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Namespace Security
    Public Class Encryption
        Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, _
                                          ByVal passPhrase As String, _
                                          ByVal saltValue As String, _
                                          ByVal hashAlgorithm As String, _
                                          ByVal passwordIterations As Integer, _
                                          ByVal initVector As String, _
                                          ByVal keySize As Integer) _
                                  As String

            ' Convert strings into byte arrays.
            ' Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
            ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8 
            ' encoding.
            Dim initVectorBytes As Byte()
            initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

            Dim saltValueBytes As Byte()
            saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

            ' Convert our plaintext into a byte array.
            ' Let us assume that plaintext contains UTF8-encoded characters.
            Dim plainTextBytes As Byte()
            plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)

            ' First, we must create a password, from which the key will be derived.
            ' This password will be generated from the specified passphrase and 
            ' salt value. The password will be created using the specified hash 
            ' algorithm. Password creation can be done in several iterations.
            Dim password As PasswordDeriveBytes
            password = New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, _
                                               saltValueBytes, _
                                               hashAlgorithm, _
                                               passwordIterations)

            ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
            ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
            Dim keyBytes As Byte()
            keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)

            ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
            Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged
            symmetricKey = New RijndaelManaged()

            ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
            ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

            ' Generate encryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
            ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
            ' bytes.
            Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
            encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

            ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
            Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream
            memoryStream = New MemoryStream()

            ' Define cryptographic stream (always use Write mode for encryption).
            Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream
            cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, _
                                            encryptor, _
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            ' Start encrypting.
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

            ' Finish encrypting.
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()

            ' Convert our encrypted data from a memory stream into a byte array.
            Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte()
            cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray()

            ' Close both streams.
            memoryStream.Close()
            cryptoStream.Close()

            ' Convert encrypted data into a base64-encoded string.
            Dim cipherText As String
            cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)

            ' Return encrypted string.
            Encrypt = cipherText
        End Function

        ' <summary>
        ' Decrypts specified ciphertext using Rijndael symmetric key algorithm.
        ' </summary>
        ' <param name="cipherText">
        ' Base64-formatted ciphertext value.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="passPhrase">
        ' Passphrase from which a pseudo-random password will be derived. The 
        ' derived password will be used to generate the encryption key. 
        ' Passphrase can be any string. In this example we assume that this 
        ' passphrase is an ASCII string.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="saltValue">
        ' Salt value used along with passphrase to generate password. Salt can 
        ' be any string. In this example we assume that salt is an ASCII string.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="hashAlgorithm">
        ' Hash algorithm used to generate password. Allowed values are: "MD5" and
        ' "SHA1". SHA1 hashes are a bit slower, but more secure than MD5 hashes.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="passwordIterations">
        ' Number of iterations used to generate password. One or two iterations
        ' should be enough.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="initVector">
        ' Initialization vector (or IV). This value is required to encrypt the 
        ' first block of plaintext data. For RijndaelManaged class IV must be 
        ' exactly 16 ASCII characters long.
        ' </param>
        ' <param name="keySize">
        ' Size of encryption key in bits. Allowed values are: 128, 192, and 256. 
        ' Longer keys are more secure than shorter keys.
        ' </param>
        ' <returns>
        ' Decrypted string value.
        ' </returns>
        ' <remarks>
        ' Most of the logic in this function is similar to the Encrypt 
        ' logic. In order for decryption to work, all parameters of this function
        ' - except cipherText value - must match the corresponding parameters of 
        ' the Encrypt function which was called to generate the 
        ' ciphertext.
        ' </remarks>
        Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String, _
                                       ByVal passPhrase As String, _
                                       ByVal saltValue As String, _
                                       ByVal hashAlgorithm As String, _
                                       ByVal passwordIterations As Integer, _
                                       ByVal initVector As String, _
                                       ByVal keySize As Integer) _
                               As String

            ' Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into byte
            ' arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
            ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
            ' encoding.
            Dim initVectorBytes As Byte()
            initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)

            Dim saltValueBytes As Byte()
            saltValueBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

            ' Convert our ciphertext into a byte array.
            Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte()
            cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)

            ' First, we must create a password, from which the key will be 
            ' derived. This password will be generated from the specified 
            ' passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using
            ' the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in
            ' several iterations.
            Dim password As PasswordDeriveBytes
            password = New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, _
                                               saltValueBytes, _
                                               hashAlgorithm, _
                                               passwordIterations)

            ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
            ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
            Dim keyBytes As Byte()
            keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keySize / 8)

            ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
            Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged
            symmetricKey = New RijndaelManaged()

            ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
            ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

            ' Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
            ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
            ' bytes.
            Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform
            decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

            ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
            Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream
            memoryStream = New MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes)

            ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
            Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream
            cryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, _
                                            decryptor, _
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Read)

            ' Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
            ' will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
            ' plaintext is never longer than ciphertext.
            Dim plainTextBytes As Byte()
            ReDim plainTextBytes(cipherTextBytes.Length)

            ' Start decrypting.
            Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer
            decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, _
                                                   0, _
                                                   plainTextBytes.Length)

            ' Close both streams.
            memoryStream.Close()
            cryptoStream.Close()

            ' Convert decrypted data into a string. 
            ' Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-encoded.
            Dim plainText As String
            plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, _
                                                0, _
                                                decryptedByteCount)

            ' Return decrypted string.
            Decrypt = plainText
        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

[I didn't write it](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Code.aspx?Source=EncryptionCS&Title=Symmetric%20Key%20Encryption&Lang=C%23), but I use it... works really well.

Comment: -1 for suggesting to roll your own and ignoring all the important 'details' like key management.