# Full-disk encryption or application level encryption?

Tags: encryption

As an example, I am planning to host a Redis database with persistence on a server. To protect the data on the disk, I think, I have two options: A) Do read/write operations via an encryption layer. B) Apply Full Disk Encryption (FDE) and let Redis to read/write as usual.

What are the pros and cons of the both the approaches above? What factors should I consider?

There seems to be some similarity here [Database encryption or application level encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002184/database-encryption-or-application-level-encryption) It is about db and application level encryption; but, my question is about the disk and an application (such as a db) level.

Comment: It also depends what scenarios you're trying to protect against.

Comment: @iThink well, wouldn't Redis (or any other application) incur an overhead while implementing a encryption solution? In some cases, the software vendor may even apply steeper charges for utilizing encryption features. What if the software vendor insisted on cryptographic hardware for their encryption solution?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Basically, similar to laptops; that is, even if the disk is stolen, the data couldn't be retrieved because the full disk is encrypted. (Or, am I being too naive? )

Comment: I think it really depends on how valuable to you your data is - is it worth hard disk encyrption? Are your harddisks at risk of being stolen? Application encryption may be enough. I have no idea if Redis would incur an overhead.  I would first assess exactly what you need before you decide on what you want.

Comment: Apart from value of the data, the one other parameter I am looking at is the ease of application development and minimizing any other installation overheads. If I had FDE in place, then (I am guessing) applications needn't change as the protection is offered by the disk itself.

Comment: Yes, if you're only trying to protect against the case of a stolen hard drive, full disk encryption makes more sense; simpler and effective. But that won't help you whenever someone manages to access the disk through a running system.

Comment: Thijsvandien, the last sentence...how do you mean?